# How to select two additional columns from another table based on id in the main table?

Tags: php, mysql

How to select two additional columns from another table based on id in the main table?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM tbl_setup t1, tbl_specialty t2
WHERE t1.app_id = 12
```

Comment: two additional column from which table, table t2? or other one ?

Comment: depends entirely on the db structure and whether there is a common field between the tables.

Comment: show us your table structure and give more details please

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_setup t1 
JOIN tbl_speciality t2
ON t1.app_idd = t2.t1_app_id
```

I am not sure, but I don't think you can use "$" in a MySQL column name without running into problems later.

A nice explanation of MySQL Joins:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/